# scalling and plotting 2d sensor data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a sensor data whose value varies from 0 to 65536 as the data type is uint16. I want to draw a 2D plot which should vary from -3000 to +3000 on X-axis with respect to time.

For example if in my data set I get

0     equivalent to -3000
32768  equivalent to 0 
65536  equivalent to 3000Please kindly excuse if the question is very trivial as I am beginner to MATLAB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Data; %here you have your data
time; %here your time
top=3000;
bot=-3000;
maxData=65536


scale=top-bot;

Data=Data*scale/maxData+bot; %rescale your data and apply the offset.

plot(Data,time);
```

You can change a lot of things in the plotting options.
For example if you want to plot the data as circles and in red do the following:

```
plot(Data,time,'ro') %r stands for red and o for circle
```

you can find a lot of information about plotting [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Comment: I think your formula should have a `+bot` at the end instead of `-bot`, otherwise the data will have the range 3000 to 9000 instead of -3000 to 3000.

Comment: @wakjah damn, in mathemathics the fault is allways the minus!